# В чём отличия создания переменных через ":" и "="? (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, response

Учусь работать с api на python. Не понимаю отличия наименования переменных, если это конечно переменные. В общем смотрел курс и увидел там такую строку кода при get запросе

```py
result_get: Response = Petstore_api.get_new_pet(self.pet_id)
```

Не понимаю чем она отличается от обычной переменной

```py
result_get_1 = Petstore_api.get_new_pet(self.pet_id)
```

Зачем писать через двоеточие ":", результат ведь один и тот же. Прикрепляю картинку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ни в чём и незачем

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В первом случае, где используется двоеточие, там просто уточняется тип данных, который будет храниться, он может даже не соответствовать, но просто указывается, чтобы код проще читать.
Во втором случае запись точно такая же, но не указывается тип, вот и всё.
Разницы нет никакой.

Comment: "Response" после двоеточия это такой тип? Не видел такого просто

Comment: @fron321 в вашем коде вы лучше нас знаете, где какие типы вы создаёте и используете

Comment: @fron321, в качестве типа может выступать любой класс. И, по-видимому, класс `Response` тянется с библиотекой, которая выполняет запросы

Answer (score 2):

Как вам уже указали это тип данных переменной после которой стоит знак `:`.

Обязательно указываю, что данная запись не имеет функционала валидации типов данных. Это для удобства и понимания кода.

Также IDE умеют понимать и схватывать данные подсказки

Простой пример, код

```py
from random import randint

a:int = randint()
с = randint()
```

справа вызов функции и не всегда очевидно (в примере очевидно, но не для всех), что будет присвоено переменной, поэтому удобно указать при ее определении и при использовании данных переменных в коде дальше `VScode` подскажет, какой тип данных имеет та или иная переменная

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите, переменная `c` не имеет подсказки по типу данных и имеет значение `Any`.

Насчет типа данных `Response`. Библиотека `requests` имеет такой тип данных и ничто не ограничивает писать подсказки, используя это

```py
from requests import Response, get

b:Response = get("https://google.com")
```

Да, хоть для собственноручно написанных типов

```py
class MyType():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.value = 5


m:MyType = MyType()
```

Comment: У вас какая-то плохая IDE. Нормальная IDE сможет показать тип и для переменной `c` тоже, например PyCharm https://i.stack.imgur.com/9miRV.png

Comment: И для переменной `b` без аннотации тоже https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0QsV.png

Comment: И для `m` аналогично https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2tJF.png

Comment: @andreymal ничего не могу с собой поделать, но PyCharm меня подбешивает, я прям нервничаю

Comment: @andreymal если писать, а не целенаправлено узнавать, на ходу тоже подхватывает? в момент написания имени переменной

Comment: Кстати, на первом скриншоте нормальная IDE ещё и настойчиво намекает фразой «Non-ASCII characters», что вы переменную назвали русской буквой `с` :)

Comment: @andreymal все равно не пойду на PyCharm =)

Comment: Не уверен, что конкретно вы имеете в виду, но по крайней мере при обращении к переменной PyCharm успешно предлагает автодополнение со списком доступных в объекте полей и функций https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fBpd.png